# How can I do a model.fit inside a tf.function

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to speed up some code by enclosing functions in `@tf.function` decorators.  I see that I can get `model.predict(x)` to work as `model(x)`, but is there a similar thing for `model.fit()`?

I'm using tensorflow 2.5.

Comment: when we do `model.fit`, it already runs in a graph model (`@tf.function`). what's your end goal?

Comment: I'm doing reinforcement learning where predictions and fits happen many times within a loop, with very small batches.  Some examples I've looked at use gradientTape and manual weight updates, but I'm hoping to avoid this.

Comment: GradientTape with @tf.function should be faster than model.fit